# .htaccess rewrite with subdomain AND directories to variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Trying to get something like this to work but only the first scenario works. Basically I have three variables I need to pass, and these are the three scenarios:

## 1

cat.domain.com
**should go to:**
index.php?pet=cat

## 2

cat.domain.com/orange.html
**should go to:**
index.php?pet=cat&color=orange

## 3

cat.domain.com/orange/fluffy.html
**should go to:**
index.php?pet=cat&color=orange&name=fluffy

I can only get the first to work with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?pet=%2 [L]
```

But when I try this for #2 it doesn't seem to work or detect the "color"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?pet=%2&color=%3 [L]
```

How would I write #2 and #3? Please help!

Comment: You can't do this with subdomain unless you really have the subdomain.

Comment: I'm using wildcard subdomains and the subdomain works great, it's the sub directories that I can't figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URI data is *not part of the HTTP Host field*, therefore, you can't match against it in a `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. Use the pattern in the rule to match against that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?pet=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?pet=%2&color=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([/]+)\.html$ index.php?pet=%2&color=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: That seems to work ONLY if I don't include the first one (#1). #1 breaks scenario #2 and #3 for some unknown reason they get neither "color" or "name". I tried moving the #1 after #2 and #3 and that didn't help. However, if I remove #1, scenario #2 and #3 gets all variables + subdomain. Any clue why it might be acting strange like that?

Comment: @unclepete Not sure why that's happening, those rules work perfectly fine in my vanilla test environment. Have you tried including a `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Totally works now. I typed something incorrectly in the htaccess and in my haste I used "?pet=cat" instead of "index.php?pet=cat" and that made it choke on that line, but still not sure why! Huge thanks!